# Array Intersection in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a table with a array type column named `writer` which has the values like `array[value1, value2]`, `array[value2, value3]`.... etc.

I am doing `self join` to get results which have common values between arrays. I tried:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT R2.writer FROM table R1 JOIN table R2 ON R1.id != R2.id WHERE ARRAY_INTERSECTION(R1.writer, R2.writer)[0] is not null ")
```

And

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT R2.writer FROM table R1 JOIN table R2 ON R1.id != R2.id WHERE ARRAY_INTERSECT(R1.writer, R2.writer)[0] is not null ")
```

But got same exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   Undefined function: 'ARRAY_INTERSECT'. This function is neither a
>   registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in
>   the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 80

Probably Spark SQL does not support `ARRAY_INTERSECTION` and `ARRAY_INTERSECT`. How can I achieve my goal in `Spark SQL`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need an udf:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

spark.udf.register("array_intersect", 
  (xs: Seq[String], ys: Seq[String]) => xs.intersect(ys))
```

and then check if intersection is empty:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT size(array_intersect(array('1', '2'), array('3', '4'))) = 0").show
+-----------------------------------------+
|(size(UDF(array(1, 2), array(3, 4))) = 0)|
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                     true|
+-----------------------------------------+


scala> spark.sql("SELECT size(array_intersect(array('1', '2'), array('1', '4'))) = 0").show
+-----------------------------------------+
|(size(UDF(array(1, 2), array(1, 4))) = 0)|
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                    false|
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 14):

Since Spark 2.4 [`array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_intersect) function can be used directly in SQL

```scala
spark.sql(
  "SELECT array_intersect(array(1, 42), array(42, 3)) AS intersection"
).show()
```

```
+------------+
|intersection|
+------------+
|        [42]|
+------------+
```

and `Dataset` API:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_intersect

Seq((Seq(1, 42), Seq(42, 3)))
  .toDF("a", "b")
  .select(array_intersect($"a", $"b") as "intersection")
  .show()
```

```
+------------+
|intersection|
+------------+
|        [42]|
+------------+
```

Equivalent functions are also present in the other languages:

- [`pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=array_intersect#pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect) in PySpark.
- [`SparkR::array_intersect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/column_collection_functions) in SparkR.