# How to cast Column to Array[Long] in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a udf which looks like this:

```
def foo : (ids: Array[Long], knownIds: Array[Long]) : Boolean = {
for (knownId <- knownIds) {
    if(ids.contains(knownId)) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And, my data frame looks like this:

```
 |-- abc: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- def: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

I'm calling this udf as follows:

```
def foo1 (ids: Array[Long]) => Boolean = foo(ids, knownIds)
val fooUdf = udf(foo1)
myDataFrame.filter(fooUdf($"ids")).count()
```

How can I cast a ColumnName to Array[Long] to use this udf? I already have the array of knownIds separately in my scala code, so knownIds isn't a column of dataframe.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `array_contains`.

Comment: doesn't help when I have to look for intersection between two arrays.

Comment: What you have written is a Scala method. Try writing UDFs like `val arr_intersect = udf ( (seq1: Array[Long] , seq2: Array[Long]) => !(seq1.intersect(seq2).isEmpty) )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array Intersection in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708014/array-intersection-in-spark-sql)

Comment: Actually I registered this foo method as a udf and tried it. I didn't put those details earlier in my question, now I updated my question.

Comment: @ShaikZakirHussain After edit I've revoked my close vote. Please see my answer with  `lit` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lit` function:

```
myDataFrame.filter(fooUdf($"ids", lit(knownIDs))).count()
```

Where `lit` is a function from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`.

BTW. Your UDF function argument will be of type WrappedArray. It's better to change Array to Seq, because you will get runtime errors with Array