# merge set type columns using spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two datasets with columns that have the type of a set (for example, a column generated by the `collect_set` function)

I want to merge them in some join ... ie something like:

```
SELECT
   ...
   SOME_MERGE_FUNCTION(x.x_set, y.y_set) as unioned_set
FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN y ON ...
```

is there a function like `SOME_MERGE_FUNCTION` in spark sql which will basically create the union of `x_set` and `y_set` ?

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost there is no such thing as *set* column. `collect_list` returns `ArrayType` column.

Also there is no built-in function for set intersection. Best you can do is to use `UserDefinedFunction`, for example like the one shown in [Array Intersection in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42708014)

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_set(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)