# How to verify an array contain another array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that contain 4 columns.

Example Dataframe:

```
id                       |  name                          | age |  job
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
     ["98475", "748574"] |  ["98475",748574]              |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
      ["75473","98456"]  |   ["98456"]                    |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
      ["23456","28596"]  |   ["84758","56849","86954"]      
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to compare 2 columns `(array<string> types)`:

Example:

```
Array_A (id)  | Array_B(name)
------------------------------
```

if all the values in the Array_B are matches are the values in the Array_A ==> ok

if all the values in the Array_B are in the array_A ==> medium

if the values of the Array_B are not exist in the array_A ==> not found

I did an UDF:

```
def contains(x,y):
        z = len(set(x) - set(y))
        if ((z == 0) & (set(x) == set(y))):
            return "ok"
        elif (set(y).isin(set(x))) & (z != 0):
            return "medium"
        else set(y) != set(x):
            return "not found in raw"


contains_udf = udf(contains)
```

Then:

```
new_df= df.withColumn(
    "new_column",
    F.when(
        (df.id.isNotNull() & df.name.isNotNull()),
        contains_udf(df.id,df.name)
    ).otherwise(
        F.lit(None)
    )

)
```

I got this error:

```
else set(y) != set(x):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I resolve it using udf or another solution like array_contains perhaps ?
Thank you

Comment: You don't need a condition in front of `else`. Maybe you meant `elif set(y) != set(x)` And if you are using sets, it's probably best to use set properties like `.issubset`, `.issuperset` etc. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset

Comment: If you're using spark version 2.4+, you don't need a `udf` for this. You can use [`array_intersect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55003177/5858851)

Comment: @pault I'm using  spark 2.2
Some help please. Thank you

Comment: @verojoucla did the solution I provided help?

Comment: @Sid I got this error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @verojoucla, by `not found in raw`, you mean all values in B are missing from A or any B is missing from A? how do you want to handle empty array of `x` or `y`?

Comment: About the not found in raw, I mean all values in B are not found in A, like in the third line in my example. In fact always I compare array B by array A. About the empty array, I changed my code and I edited my question above, before run the udf I added a test on my columns. But always I have the same error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @verojoucla, `sex(x) == set(y)` should already have `z==0`. I think `z` is not very useful in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Buckeye14Guy and @Sid pointed out the main problems in your code, you might also need to clean out some of the logic:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def contains(x,y): 
  try:
    sx, sy = set(x), set(y) 
    if len(sy) == 0: 
        return 'list is empty'
    elif sx == sy: 
        return "ok"    
    elif sy.issubset(sx): 
        return "medium"  
    # below none of sy is in sx
    elif sx - sy == sx: 
        return "none found in raw"  # including empty x
    else: 
        return "some missing in raw"
  # in exception, for example `x` or `y` is None (not a list)
  except:
    return "not an iterable or other errors"

udf_contains = udf(contains, 'string')

df.withColumn('new_column', udf_contains('id', 'name')).show(truncate=False)
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|id             |name                 |new_column       |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|[98475, 748574]|[98475, 748574]      |ok               |
|[75473, 98456] |[98456]              |medium           |
|[23456, 28596] |[84758, 56849, 86954]|none found in raw|
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
else set(y) != set(x):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because an `else` statement doesn't require a condition. It contains code to be executed only if none of the previous conditions are met. Use instead:

```py
elif set(y) != set(x):
    #code
```

**OR**

```py
else :
    #code
```

Comment: You will only get that error if you used `import set`. Remove that line.

Comment: `set` isn't a module- it's an object type. No need to import.